# Android setRotation usage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framework

I am wondering if I can change the device's orienation (respecting respective app policies) using IWindowManager service's setRotation. I am not going to issue this from application layer, instead there is a requirement to change the device orientation (to either landscape / portrait) from frameworks layer itself.

Therefore in order to achieve this, I have written a C utility daemon which calls my java code using Binder IPC mechanism to invoke my service's exposed method (lets call it myfunc() )

In myfunc, I have something as follows:-

```
IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService
("window")).setRotation(0,true,0)
```

But it looks like the device orientation is not changed. Any suggestions please / inputs?

Thanks,

Comment: According to Diane Hackborn this is not allowed.  See the following thread. Unfortunately it doe not provide an answer so I am posting as a comment http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5e56032f03e48127